# Is it possible to view related lists in a categorized view in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: list

I am new to Sharepoint.  I am a Lotus Notes developer and my company is converting all our Lotus Notes applications to Sharepoint 2010.  There is no budget for training so I am trying to figure things out on my own.  My question:  Is it possible to view multiple related SP lists in a view ?  For example I have 4 lists : ClientNames, Special Procedures, ContactInfo and FeeSchedules.  It is possible to view the list info like this :

```
Client One 
  Special Procedures ( for Client One )
  Contact Info ( for CLient One)
  Fee Schedules ( for Client One)
Client Two
  Special Procedures ( for Client Two)
  Contact Info ( for CLient Two)
  Fee Schedules ( for Client Two)
```

etc.

Is this possible ?  If so, what is the best way to accomplish this ?  Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you all very much for your answers. I will use the tips you all provided and post my progress!

Answer (score 1):

Debby,

I hope you already know how to connect lists using Lookup columns.. If not, please let me know..

Out of the box, you can create Connected Web Parts to build such a View.. It won't be a single View, it will be different views from different lists but all connected to show meaningful information..

A sample can be seen [Connecting web parts with a selector and a detail pane (SharePoint 2010 version)](http://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/05/21/connecting-web-parts-with-a-selector-and-a-detail-pane-sharepoint-2010-version/)..

You can also customize the List View page itself to achieve these results..

However if you are looking for more clean approach, you might need to customize and write your own Visual Web Part..

Answer (score 0):

Arsalan has some good core ways to do this.

An additional method would be to use Javascript to access the client object model (I would suggest using JQuery and SPServies) to grab the data and then display it yourself. This could be a better option if you have the Javascript skills and want a polished look.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built in feature in SP2010 and SP2013 called "related lists" that should come close to your requirement.

Here is a blog post to get you started:

http://sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=74